# jsonDecode error in flutter | expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type '_JsonMap'

Tags: flutter

I am having an issue with decoding my api response, searched and tried different solutions but none worked.

```
Future<Artwork> getArtwork() async {
  
  const urlApi =
      'http://localhost:6060/getartwork?RequestID=t26ypmg55';
  
  var dio = Dio();
  var response = await dio.get(urlApi);
  
  if (response.statusCode == 200) { 
    //final json = "[ ${response.data} ]";
    final map = jsonDecode(response.data)  as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Artwork.fromJson(map);
  } else { 
    log("Exception Section");
    throw Exception(response.data);
  }
}
```

there is also factory code for the struct

```
factory Artwork.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Artwork(
      id: json['id'],
      imageUrl: json['imageUrl'], 
....
```

error:

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type '_JsonMap'
```

when I debug, this is what I see as the response.data

```
_JsonMap ({Id: 123456, ImageUrl: ohO0P8VXzfzDMCk6ZYJP6jAQEF9EEdkzQjKTeoPbttUHbrGQA/out-0.png, CampaignId: campaign155faghf, CreatedTime: 2022-12-04 20:36:11.335297 +0000 UTC, CompleteTime: 2022-12-04 20:36:23.934309 +0000 UTC, ImageList: [/ohO0P8VXzfzDMCk6ZYJP6jAQEF9EEdkzQjKTeoPbttUHbrGQA/out-0.png] })
```

the error message is not clear;
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/41174

None of the below worked;

using `http.StreamedRequest`

using `request.sink`

wrapping the json with [ ] as suggested by another post.

Comment: You're calling `jsonDecode` on data that's *already* been decoded. According to the `package:dio` documentation, it "will parse [the] response string to [a] json object automatically when the content-type of [the] response is 'application/json'". Just use `response.body` directly instead of calling `jsonDecode` on it.

Comment: This resolved it. Thanks, it was simple : )